# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 724. MiB for an array with shape (9742, 9742) and data type float64

Tags: python

I was trying to run a training module from a Github repo. But when I run the code it gives me MemoryError: Unable to allocate 724. MiB for an array with shape (9742, 9742) and data type float64 error. Full Code is on https://pastebin.com/4gD34s28.
My error is occuring when i use it in Django project, but in core python it works well.
Dataset : http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word',ngram_range=(1, 2),min_df=0, stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(movies['genres'])

tfidf_matrix.shape
print('hello1')

cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

Comment: Please notify me why the error is in Django project and not Core python or Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Is django running on your local machine or a server somewhere else? Your process has a low memory limit.

Comment: it is running on Local Machine

Comment: How does the code come into play "in the django project"? I don't know django but I suspect there's information missing here.

Comment: Given a particular movie_id, find the other movies which
are the most similar to it. So... Ill pass the dictionary to the views and hence the code will be displayed on the django app to the user